# Dropdownlist Box - C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a very basic syntax question on Populating a dropdownlist box from dataset. I want the first column or Dropdownlistbox.selectedIndex(-1) = "" .

i.e) First Column Should be Empty - Instead of - SELECT -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fir blank first item use below:

```
ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem(" ", 0))
```

then use loop to enter items from dataset

Comment: drp.DataSource = objBL.GetSortCode();
            drp.DataTextField = "SORTCODE1";
            drp.DataValueField = "SORTCODE1";
            drp.DataBind();

Comment: then make appenddataitems to true in the dropdown.

Comment: i did, what else .. where i need to add that line ??

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

Answer (score 1):

suppose dt is the table with data....having col1 as value column and col2 as Display column,
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] ="-1";
dr[1] = " ";

dt.Rows.InsertAt(row,0);

ddl.DataSource = dt;

Comment: I bind my Dropdown as ...  drpSortCodePlacedOrder.DataSource = objBL.GetSalisburySortCode();
           
            drpSortCodePlacedOrder.DataTextField = "SORTCODE1";
            drpSortCodePlacedOrder.DataValueField = "SORTCODE1";
            drpSortCodePlacedOrder.DataBind();

Answer (score 1):

If you are binding from a collection:
Set it up like this (note AppendDataBoundItems...)

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```